# VS 2013 LightSwitch won't attach a data source

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to create a LightSwitch project in VS 2013 with Update 3. I right-click on the .Server, click Add Data Source, select Database, click Next and I get the following error:

"The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' threw an exception."

I have repaired Visual Studio, re-installed it, taken Oracle out of my Environment Variables. I still get this error. Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Does the current project have any external data sources, if so, what are they attaching to (e.g. SQL, OData, etc...)?  If you create a brand new LightSwitch project and try to setup an external data source, does this error still happen?

Comment: This is a brand new project with no external data sources and the problem still occurs. If I do add any data sources they are SQL.

Comment: Do you have some Oracle related Visual Studio Extension installed?  Sounds like a possible compatibility problem.  If so, try uninstalling it and see if that helps.  If it doesn't, follow the steps in this blog post to get a stack trace (which will help) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2013/08/16/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-in-lightswitch.aspx